# CSS Spacing Issue - IE6/7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Site loads fine in IE8,9,FF & Chrome. I can't seem to remedy the issue thats causing the spacing I see in IE6 an IE7 thought. If someone could take a look, it would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.textlinkbrokers.com/

```
#wrap {
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 1em;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
min-width: 770px;
background: #fff url(../img/corner.gif) top left no-repeat;
}

/* js hack for IE6 to obey min-max width */
#wrap {
width: expression(document.body.clientWidth < 772? "770" : document.body.clientWidth > 2000? "2000px" : "auto");
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and CSS code in here - otherwise the question will become useless for future generations once the problem is fixed

Comment: Yeah, post some code and a screenshot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your problem is stemming from #wrap in main.css.  You have a min-width and a max-width.  When I turned off the max-width, the gap disappears in IE7.  I am not seeing the same problem in IE6.  I hope that helps.